# Нужна ли запятая в таком предложении

Tags: пунктуация, ссп

Intrapreneurship и почему оно необходимо крупным корпорациям.

Answer (score 1):

***Intrapreneurship, и почему оно необходимо крупным корпорациям.***

Сложносочинённое предложение, запятую перед И ставим по правилу постановки запятой в ССП.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше поставить точку.

Это т. н сегментированные заголовки.Точка ставится после первой части так называемой сегментированной конструкции, или конструкции с «двойным обозначением», состоящей из двух частей. Первая часть (сегмент, т. е. отрезок), находящаяся в начале предложения или текста и выраженная, как правило, формой именительного падежа существительного либо словосочетанием во главе с этой формой (именительный темы, или именительный представления), называет лицо, предмет, явление, которое во второй части (в последующем тексте) получает другое обозначение в форме местоимения: **Земля. На ней никто не тронет… Лишь крепче прижимайся к ней. (Сим.); Производительность труда. Как её повысить? (Газ.)**

Ср.: Кольца Сатурна. Какие они?;

Два выходных. Как их лучше использовать?;

Лесные десантники. Где их готовят?;

Эстрада. Она всегда волнует;

Comment: (1) Мне кажется, точка хороша, если первая часть называет известный читателю предмет. Но многие ли знают, что такое Intrapreneurship? Смысл заголовка, вероятно, такой: "Что такое intrapreneurship и почему оно необходимо крупным корпорациям". Нужна ли запятая в таком варианте? (2) Нужен ли знак вопроса?

Comment: Не думаю, что первая часть должна быть извстной читателю. По поводу запятой в вашем примере, думаю, она не нужна, даже если отсутствует знак вопроса. Ведь вопросительная интонация все равно сохраняется. Впрочем, в правилах пунктуации ничего об этом не сказано.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: **Intrapreneurship, и почему оно необходимо крупным корпорациям.**

Сравним два варианта:

1) Системное мышление. Что это и почему оно необходимо? ССП, общая вопросительная интонация, нет запятой.

2) Измельчение хвои, и почему оно необходимо. ССП, первое предложение назывное, общих элементов нет, ставится запятая. http://litrus.net/book/read/90046